# SharePoint installation

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have installed MOSS2007 on a server, deplyed the apps, etc. Only to find out that I should have specified a specific locations for the files - not the default C:\Inetpub\wwwroot.

How do I change that? I don't mind reinstalling MOSS, I just don't want to loose all the custom work I did.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: If answered helped you please mark it as a answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Click Start, and then select Run…
2. In the Open field enter Regedit and click OK.
3. Locate the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp key and modify the PathWWWRoot       Value data to D:\Inetpub\vroots.
4. Locate the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\ContentIndex\Catalogs\Web key and modify the Location Value data to d:\inetpub.
5. Locate the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet003\Control\ContentIndex\Catalogs\Web key and modify the Location Value data to d:\inetpub.
6. Locate the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ContentIndex\Catalogs\Web key and modify the Location Value data to d:\inetpub.

Repeat steps 1 through 6 on each Web front-end and application server.

Regards
Ashutosh Singh

[MyBlog](http://www.sharepointworld.in)